# A more efficient way to sum the difference between columns in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, vectorization, simd

For my application I have a table with these three columns: `user, item, value`

Here's some sample data:

```
user    item    value
---------------------
1       1       50
1       2       45
1       23      35
2       1       88
2       23      44
3       2       12
3       1       27
3       5       76
3       23      44
```

What I need to do is, for a given user, perform simple arithmetic against everyone else's values.

Let's say I want to compare user 1 against everyone else. The calculation looks something like this:

```
first_user    second_user    result
1             2              SUM(ABS(50-88) + ABS(35-44))
1             3              SUM(ABS(50-27) + ABS(45-12) + ABS(35-44))
```

This is currently the bottleneck in my program. For example, many of my queries are starting to take 500+ milliseconds, with this algorithm taking around 95% of the time.

I have many rows in my database and it is O(n^2) (it has to compare all of user 1's values against everyone else's matching values)

I believe I have only two options for how to make this more efficient. First, I could cache the results. But the resulting table would be huge because of the NxN space required, and the values need to be relatively fresh.

The second way is to make the algorithm much quicker. I searched for "postgres SIMD" because I think SIMD sounds like the perfect solution to optimize this. I found a couple related links like [this](https://www.pgcon.org/2014/schedule/track/Big%20Data/643.en.html) and [this](https://github.com/citusdata/postgres_vectorization_test), but I'm not sure if they apply here. Also, they seem to both be around 5 years old and relatively unmaintained.

Does Postgres have support for this sort of feature? Where you can "vectorize" a column or possibly import or enable some extension or feature to allow you to quickly perform these sorts of basic arithmetic operations against many rows?

Comment: A covering index could improve performance, if you don't already have it. In the simplified example you show, this could take the form: `create index ix1 on my_table (user, item, value)`.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have never heard of a covering index before I'll look it up thanks.

Comment: Now, if "the values need to be relatively fresh" you can also use the strategy of storing the computed values on a table, and refresh them periodically. If the day has 24 hours, you can refresh 1/24th of the users every hour; every user data will be at most 23 hours "stale". A cron job would do the trick.

Comment: There are some discussions around vectorized execution but nothing has led to a concrete implementation in the core so far. Did you try to enable [JITting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/jit.html) for those queries?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've never heard of that before either. Trying it out now but not sure if I'm doing it properly. I ran `set JIT = true;` and then `SET jit_above_cost = 10;` and `SET jit_inline_above_cost = 10;` and `SET jit_optimize_above_cost = 10;` but the query seems to still take the same amount of time.

Comment: @TheImpaler Also I tried the covering index you suggested and the query execution time did not change unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you get O(n^2) for this.  You need to look up the rows for user 1 and then read the data for everyone else.  Assuming there are few items and many users, this would be essentially O(n), where "n" is the number of rows in the table.

The query could be phrased as:

```
select t1.user, t.user, sum(abs(t.value - t1.value))
from t left join
     t t1
     on t1.item = t.item and
        t1.user <> t.user and
        t1.user = 1
group by t1.user, t.user;
```

For this query, you want an index on `t(item, user, value)`.

Comment: Well there are many items and many users. I'm already doing something similar to this and it is the cause of my bottleneck and performance issues. I have around 300 items and many many thousands of users. I think I need SIMD or something along those lines for this to run in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @RyanPeschel . . . Do you have the specified index?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using the covering index that The Impaler mentioned but it didn't seem to improve the query speed at all.

Comment: @RyanPeschel . . . That is not the index in my answer.

Comment: Ah right you are. Okay, I made that one too but the performance is still the same.